# How can I run cmake to configure my build and then run my build in one invocation?

Tags: cmake

If my project root is . and my build directory is ./build/ I normally build like:

```
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

I'd like to combine those into a single cmake invocation. Something like:

```
cd build
cmake .. --build .
```

I can't seem to find the right command line, or perhaps there isn't one.

I can't use 'cmake .. ; cmake --build .' in my context because I'm passing it to a tool that can't handle multiple invocations in one command line. But if there's some other solution, I'm interested.

Comment: There is no reason to have `cmake` and `cmake --build` combined: These commands does different things. You may create a script which calls these commands together.

Comment: @Tysvarev, Yes, I know they do different things. There are billions of computer programs that do more than one thing, and most can do them in one invocation of the program. I want something more elegant than writing a script for my situation. I haven't learned anything from your comment, and I doubt anyone else will either. Sorry you wasted your time.